# Is it possible to have a uisplitviewcontroller inside a uipopovercontroller?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I was able to successfully create the popover but I could only see the master view of the split view and not the detail view no matter how wide I made the popover. Just wondering if I have run into a limitation or if this is indeed possible?

Comment: if you only want to show the master view then whats the point of using UISplitViewController?

Comment: I think you can not do so.

Comment: I want to use the whole split view, not just the master. That's the problem - I'm only seeing the master and not the detail

Answer (score 0):

`UISplitView` must be **root** `ViewController`, for your case you can use a custom implementation of a `SplitViewController` like [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/).